# Wrapping XMLSerializer

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization, xmlserializer, facade

I wish to put the XMLSerializer behind a 'facade' class of mine so that user wont have to supply type info to the constructor. But doing this has a problem. Consider this class:

```
Class XmlFormatter
    Private Shared xs As XmlSerializer

    Public Function Deserialize(ByVal serializationStream As Stream) As Object
        Dim o As Object = Nothing
        If Not xs Is Nothing Then
            o = xs.Deserialize(serializationStream)
        End If
        Return o
    End Function

    Public Overloads Sub Serialize(ByVal serializationStream As Stream, ByVal graph As Object)
        If xs Is Nothing Then
            xs = New XmlSerializer(graph.GetType())
        End If
        xs.Serialize(serializationStream, graph)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that the user of this class cannot use Deserialize without first using Serialize because the XMLSerializer instance is created in Serialize and it is shared. But using Deserialize without this instance will simply return Nothing.
Can this problem be solved?

Comment: What is the scenario here? Does the caller not know the type expected?

Comment: I dont want the caller to know the type. You see, i am trying to make it look like binary and SOAP formatters. Caller call: Dim f as XMLFormatter = New XMLFormatter() and then f.Serialize()/Deserialize()

Comment: You mean "like BinaryFormatter"; many binary serializers exist that work the XmlSerializer way (I.e. you need to know the type), and frankly I support that use-case. Embedding the type is a bad thing.

Comment: Why cant the formatter get the type of the object that is to be serialized? Usually when i use BinaryFormatter instance, i dont have to supply the type of the object. Atleast for a simple case. That is what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: By the way, if you don't care what the layout is, you *miught* find NetDataContractSerializer satisfying'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlSerializer does not include the type, because it is a design decision on XmlSerializer that **the type is not important**. The following are 100% compatible, for example:

```
namespace X {
    public class A {
        public string B;
    }
}
namespace Y.Z {
    [XmlRoot("A"), XmlType("A")]
    public class C {
        [XmlElement("B")]
        public string D {get;set;}
    }
}
```

This is IMO the most useful approach, and allows:

- simple use with generated/proxy types
- switching between POCO/DTO
- cross-platform and cross-architecture usage (for example consuming a "full .NET" service from WP7/SL/XNA
- simple versioning without a strict client/server tie

Basically, I'm of the opinion that the client absolutely **should** know what it is expecting, and that relying on the type is the wrong approach.